# Parsing comma separated key value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to turn

```
realm="https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/registry/auth",service="registry.digitalocean.com",scope="registry:catalog:*"
```

To

```json
{
  realm: "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/registry/auth",
  service: "registry.digitalocean.com",
  scope: "registry:catalog:*"
}
```

I don't know what does it call, but I think there should be easier to parse these type of format. I wonder if there is existing library or easier way to parse this one?

Currently, this is what I do, but I feel it is not reliable.

```js
auth = `realm="https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/registry/auth",service="registry.digitalocean.com",scope="registry:catalog:*"`;
const convertToJsonString = '{"' + auth.replace(/="/g, `":"`).replace(/",/g, `","`) + '}';
JSON.parse(convertToJsonString);
```

---

What I have to achieve is to parse the Www-Authenticate header as the following spec:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.1
- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-4.1

I am surprised that something that common has no existing library for parsing or maybe I don't know where to look for.

Comment: Will there be any instances of unescaped `="` and `",` in your value(s)?

Comment: @Terry
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-4.1 According to spec, everything should be escape. But as I check their spec a moment ago, my code will fail if there is space between , and when there is something like `key="Hello\","`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all entries are well-formed and `",` within the values are escaped with backslashes (`\",`), then the following incantation does the trick:

```
Object.fromEntries(
  s
    .replace(/(?<!\\)",/g, '"\n')  // replace separators by newlines
    .split("\n")  // split by newlines
    .map((r) => /^(.+?)=(.+?)$/.exec(r))  // split by first equals
    .map(([, k, v]) => [k, JSON.parse(v)]),  // parse value as JSON string
)
```

Comment: This look good. I will try and wait for other people answer. If there is no better answer. I will mark it as answer. Thanks.